# define: is there a way to expand arguments?

Tags: c++, c

`T()` is a macro

I have many things like:

```
MACRODOWN(T(P), T(E), T(X), T(R), T(T), T(H), T(A), T(F))
MACRODOWN(T(H), T(A), T(F))
MACRODOWN(T(Z), T(A))
```

I'd like to define a macro that would work like this:

```
MACRODOWN(TT(P,E,X,R,T,H,A,F))
MACRODOWN(TT(H,A,F))
MACRODOWN(TT(Z,A))
```

And they would exand, of course, to the first macros above.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Have a look at Boost.Preprocessor

Comment: Why do you use macros at all?

Comment: I'm using macros for the QMK firmware = for embedded program, this kinddof declare local variables (it seems it's better like this for embedded stuff, it's not my cup of tea I dont know more, just a wild guess).

Comment: "it seems it's better like this for embedded stuff" Most certainly not. This just looks like some crazy macro meta programming. Look at ways to get rid of the macros.

Comment: Just had a look at that library. It is really horribly written, one big goo of somebody's secret garage marco language. Basically just a big wall of `BLIP BLOP X Y MACRO STUFF DO THINGS` without any identifier naming policy whatesover. Avoid that crap if you can.

Comment: (Writing a keyboard driver for a MCU isn't rocket science. No need to bloat it to oblivion.)

Comment: QMK firmware developper and kiibohd firmware developper are one of the best C/embedded developpers around. Please be less cheeky and take a deeper look. Please think first "if those guys are using tons of macros, there's a reason behind, *they're not stupid there must be a logical reason*". Instead of thinking "avoid macros if you can, those who use them a lot make only crappy stuff". Thank you. If you've taken a careful look at the qmk firmware, you would have seen how many keyboards they support, and how many drivers + keymap configuration they handle. Try to do 1/100th of what they've done.

Comment: @Lundin I'll take your advice and try to make my own function to avoid big macros anyway, because I guess you're good too. Is there a way to see expanded macros before they're compiled (with gcc)?

Comment: `gcc -E` shows you the preprocessed source.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages, with distinct solutions. Pick one.

Comment: @OlivierPons The need for macros like these pop up when maintaining larger code bases that had a poor design from scratch - it is a certain sign of code rot. If you look at larger professional protocol stacks, RTOS and similar, they face the very same portability problems, yet they manage without some `BLIP(BLOP)` macros. There is not necessarily a relation between the end result of the application and the quality of the code. Linux for example, is a very successful application, yet it contains some of the most notorious C code ever written.

Comment: Summary: It is important to call out bad code for what it is. Otherwise less experienced devs might think that the code is good and start to imitate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: No, The GCC can't do argument expansion. The C Preprocessor only supports 2 kind of macros: Object-like macros and function-like macros. What you are using is function-like macro. A Macro is code which has been given a name. A function-like macro expands its code trough the compiler, but take care about this, only its code, not its arguments, and if contains other macros the compiler will expand too the other macros code. The Official page of the GCC (https://gcc.gnu.org/), NEVER reports that it supports argument expansion, or what I see what you want, function argument separation at expansion time. The GCC supports only the normal macro code expansion (here is the specific article about supported macros: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html),  so there is no way to do function argument separation at expansion time. But you can perfectly define the macros like the second example you give, but of course will not do argument expansion.

Comment: `gcc` is not the only C compiler in the World and the question is not tagged `gcc`. I think your answer is right but it unnecessarily focuses on `gcc`.

Comment: He never said an specific compiler, so I take the GCC as example.

Comment: Also, for the most commercial compilers it is the same behavior, because the compiler programming enterprises or organizations has to follow the most important C standard, the ANSI C, if they want a comercial, functional and well software engineered compiler.

Comment: You could use italic instead of caps, to say "never", I feel like you shout and I annoyed you with my question...

Comment: Sorry It was not my intention, will keep it in mind next time I answer a question, I'm new in stack overflow.

Comment: unless I missed something, this answer is not practically correct, because argument expansion can be emulated uo to some fixed arg count ...

Comment: My point was that your answer appears to be specific to gcc, but it generally applies to all C compilers. If gcc is just an example, You should say so e.g. "The answer is: No, For example, the GCC compiler... " and everything else can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

a boost preprocessor solution could be

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/transform.hpp>


#define TT(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM( BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM( TT_, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__) ) )
#define TT_(_1,_2,E) T(E)

TT(A,B,C,D) // T(A),T(B),T(C),T(D)
```

where is assumed variadic support and boost pp iteration limits.

Comment: Can I use the boost library with the QMK firmware (I'm sorry I'm very new to C programming), it's using gcc and it's for my Infinity Ergodox

Comment: @OlivierPons boost is for **C++**, you've erroneously tagged 2 unrelated languages to your question.

Comment: boost preprocessor should support both c and c++ compilers afaik

Comment: Would that work if (as the question asked) the `TT(...)` was an argument to a macro? i.e. `SOME_MACRO(TT(A,B,C,D))` is the same as `SOME_MACRO(T(A), T(B), T(C),T(D))`?

Comment: @JeremyP yep, for a general macro they're not equivalent of course; I assumed the MACRODOWN being a variadic pasting its __VA_ARGS__ verbatim, in this case it would work. Otherwise, you'd need to redefine the outer macro via something like BOOST_PP_EXPAND in order to delay evaluation ...